# Entity Framework 6 and composite primary key, duplicate names

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a class that looks like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Object1 Object1 { get; set; }
    public Object2 Object2 { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

MyClass is a connection table with two additional columns.

Entity Mapping:

```
public class MyClassMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        ToTable("dbo.MyClass");

        HasKey(pc => new { pc.Object1.Id, pc.Object2.Id });

        Property(x => x.Order).IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.Created).HasColumnType("DateTime").IsRequired();
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I want create a composite primary key for MyClass. I want the primary key like this:

```
HasKey(pc => new { pc.Object1.Id, pc.Object2.Id });
```

The problem is that this is not allowed.
An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

I could of course name my Id property on class Object1 to Object1Id and my Id property on class Object2 to Object2Id but I don't want that.

I could also add another property on MyClass called Id and use this as primary key but want to avoid that too.

Is there an alternative way to solve this problem?

Comment: The keys should reside in the same table, so you should add properties in `MyClass` corresponding to primary keys of `Object1` and `Object2` and mark them as foreign keys and then use them in your `HasKey`. With your current code, its like saying `MyTable` has a composite key and they reside inside two tables this and that.

Comment: This is a many to many relationship like Product(Object1), Vendor(Object2) and ProductVendor(MyClass).

Comment: Since there exists non key attributes within that relationship it cannot be modeled as many-to-many relationship, but one to many in the sense that `Product` can be ordered through many `PurchaseOrder`s and each `Vendor` can receive many `PurchaseOrder`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathew (https://stackoverflow.com/users/219933/mathew) gave me some hints.

Class needs to look like this(added Object1Id and Object2Id):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Object1 Object1 { get; set; }
    public int Object1Id { get; set; }
    public Object2 Object2 { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId2 { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Entity mapping:

```
public class MyClassMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap ()
    {
        this.ToTable("dbo.MyClass");

        HasKey(pc => new { pc.Object1Id, pc.Object2Id});

        HasRequired(x => x.Object1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Object1Id);
        HasRequired(x => x.Object2).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Object2Id);
    }
}
```

This does not solve my problem with duplicate key name column named Id but I hope Entity Framework will support primary key like this in the future:

```
    HasKey(pc => new { pc.Object1.Id, pc.Object2.Id});
```

Answer (score -1):

So why not give names to anonymous type properties?

```
HasKey(pc => new { Id1 = pc.Object1.Id, Id2 = pc.Object2.Id });
```

Comment: You will get a System.InvalidOperationException.

The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'

Comment: What is a pc then, could you show context of this code line, or, better yet, a compilable sample reproducing the error?